# Labview start recording with a history buffer

Tags: labview

i would like to do a manual data recording (press button) based on a graph i see  but that it will save the data starting for "Time-1 sec" ( that after i press the recording data in will include Xsec pre samples of the recording, when stopping the recording it will stop at time 0

need to create some history buffer  that i don't know how :)

[image]

Comment: That's too broad question. My answer would be - if you'd like to create history buffer of data, then store it in the array.

Comment: 1) i am starting my DAQ and i get samples on screen in a chart
2) at s point of time(T0) i would see an interesting event that occurred  and i would like to log it to a file and have some data of the pre-event

in order for this i need that the file logging will have some buffered data (Dynamically configured based on sample rate) 
3) when pressing stop all data till the buffered is cleared should be saved.
could you help me with some example as i am missing something out here
were to place record button (in loop) how to configure the buffer ?
could you show me some basic example ?

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to do this would be to use the timing functions on the timing palette and a shift register to hold the previous time. An example of this is here:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/401535/holding-signal-true-for-x-seconds-in-labview

In the linked example, when the user presses the button a boolean value is set to true for 10 seconds, which is used to control a case structure. In this case structure you will need a true case and a false case. The true case is where you should build a data buffer, where you append data to an array. Is it necessary for your data to be a waveform, or would a double data type suffice?